# How to find the nth row for a value?

Tags: excel

How can i find the row number for the nth value in a range. For Example if I have values 1,2,1,3,4,2 in range A1:A6, then how to find the row number for the second occurence for the value 1. Trick is that one can only use functions belonging to the Sum/Count Family (sum,Sumif,Sumifs,Count,counta,countblank,Countif,CountIfs).I am able to solve the problem using '`SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$6=1,ROW($A$1:$A$6),""),B1)`'. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why only use those functions?

Comment: it is the requirement of the practice question.

Comment: is the range fixed from A1 to A6 or can the range change in length? if fixed you can do this with nested if statments and countif. use nested if with countif to check previous set of cells in range before the current referenced cell and if it is equal to 2 then check the value against the value of 1 if true you have your answer. This I am sure, is not the best solution but it is what came to me at first glance.

Comment: range is fixed from A1 to A6. But i'm trying not to use any function outside the count or sum family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume `B1` has the occurrence that you're looking for, and `B2` has the value you're looking for.

With only 6 rows you could brute-force it:

```
=(A1=B2)*(B1=1)+(A2=B2)*(COUNTIF(A1:A2,B2)=B1)*2+(A3=B2)*(COUNTIF(A1:A3,B2)=B1)*3+(A4=B2)*(COUNTIF(A1:A4,B2)=B1)*4+(A5=B2)*(COUNTIF(A1:A5,B2)=B1)*5+(A6=B2)*(COUNTIF(A1:A6,B2)=B1)*6
```

Each of the terms being summed is checking if the nth occurrence is on a specific row. For the example you gave, `(A3=B2)*(COUNTIF(A1:A3,B2)=B1)*3` will be evaluated as:

```
-> (1=1)*(2=2)*3
-> TRUE*TRUE*3
-> 3
```

All of the other terms will be 0. For example:

```
-> (A4=B2)*(COUNTIF(A1:A4,B2)=B1)*4
-> (3=1)*(2=2)*4
-> FALSE*TRUE*4
-> 0
```

If a helper column is an option, you could use this and fill down 6 rows:

`=((COUNTIF(A$1:A1,B$2)*(A1=B$2))=B$1)*(COUNTA(A$1:A1)+COUNTBLANK(A$1:A1))`

The answer would be the sum of the helper column. This solution is easily expandable--just fill it down however many rows you need, and the answer will always be the sum.

Comment: I know it's a big formula, but if it is possible for you please share the working of the formula.

Comment: @KT11 Sure. I've added an explanation in the answer.